# ! No such app as demo_app

Tags: git, heroku

I'm new to github/heroku and I am doing a rails tutorial right now. When i tried to submit my application, I get an error that says ! No such app as demo_app . However, when I did

```
git remote -v
```

I get:

```
heroku git@heroku.com:demo_app.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:demo_app.git (push)
origin git@heroku.com:schan93/demo_app.git (fetch)
origin git@heroku.com:schan93/demo_app.git (fetch)
```

but when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

i get an error that says

```
! No such app as demo_app.
```

any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pardon if this is an incorrect assumption, but I'm guessing you don't have an app on heroku called demo_app.

If this is the case, you should use the [heroku gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/heroku) to create an app as follows.

```
heroku apps:create
```

You can pass an optional name like this.

```
heroku apps:create my_app
```

That should spit out a git url which you can then add to git and you should be able to push to.